# not able to use facebook plugin with ripple emulator

Tags: cordova, ripple

I am trying to run facebook plugin 'SIMPLE example' using ripple emulator.

I already included the facebook_js_sdk.js and cdv_plgin.js and cardova.js.

config.xml is as follow.

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin"/>
<gap:plugin name="FacebookConnect">
<param name="APP_ID" value="xxx" />
<param name="APP_NAME" value="app" />
</gap:plugin>
```

I am getting error

> org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect.getLoginStatus
>
> We seem to be missing some stuff :(
>
> What is kinda cool though you can fill in the textarea to pass a json object to the callback you want to execute

Thank you.

Comment: Any luck? Having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running it using Ripple google extension, probably you are using old version.

Try out the new version as mentioned in the link below.

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/5/Ripple-is-Reborn

Also note that you can not expect every single feature to work in Ripple.

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova Facebook plugin uses the native app on the device, so I think you cant´n test your project on Ripple with this restriction.

I was trying to make a test with the Facebook Javascript SDK (and the new Ripple) and the new problem was the URL for my Facebook APP :(