# Cordova app, facebook login not working only on device

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, authentication, oauth

I have a simple Cordova app, with facebook login button that works on chrome emulator, but it doesn't work on my android device.
The code is very simple:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            });
```

In facebook login configuration I set as Valid OAuth redirect URIs the emulator URL http://localhost:4400 and it works.
But when I create the apk file and I put it on my android device it doesn't work, so I created the webview to debug my app, and I have the following error:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Removing from facebook configuration Valid OAuth redirect URIs I have the same error in the emulator.

Now I don't understand how to configure facebook login for my app, because it doesnt't have an URL (contrary to chrome emulator).

Any suggest is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to follow this tutorial [link](https://kmturley.blogspot.it/2014/10/facebook-login-inside-hybrid-app-using.html) that says that this solution works for cordova app but I have always the same error in my device...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Cordova Plugin, don´t try to use the JS SDK: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

There is no "localhost" on the device, as you don´t start a server on it.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, After executing $ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication", I called facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus but nothing happend. The emulator console show this error: missing exec: FacebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus on ripple.js

Comment: if i enter that error message in google, i get quite a few good results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425096/not-able-to-use-facebook-plugin-with-ripple-emulator